# Workfow foundation 4.0 Flow chart

Tags: workflow-foundation

We already have our own workflow engine implemented about 5 years ago, currently we are thinking of leveraging the new flow chart control in .net 4.0 for the visual presentations of our existing states.  So can we simply using this flow chart control without using other workflow foundations features?

Answer (score 0):

Using the workflow designer and controls results in a XAML file which is just XML. You are free to parse this XAML file and do something completely different with the contents like create your own workflow like objects.